# Sudden SSL Error: check_private_key:key values mismatch

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

I installed an SSL certificate (generated with openssl) on a server running Apache 2.2. After refreshing the config, I saw the site work properly.

However, this morning I discovered that the site was down. After a quick look at the logs, I noticed that Apache was not running and I was not able to restart it.

There were the following errors in the `ssl.log`

> [Tue Oct 10 14:58:48 2017] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA
>   certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
>
> [Tue Oct 10 14:58:48
>   2017] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `AddTrust External
>   CA Root' does NOT match server name!?
>
> [Tue Oct 10 14:58:48 2017]
>   [error] Unable to configure RSA server private key
>
> [Tue Oct 10 14:58:48 2017] [error] SSL Library Error: 185073780
>   error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key
>   values mismatch

Could anyone tell me why this happened? That is, the site worked for several days after the initial configuration. However, at a certain point it broke. How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: I doubt you generated a cert with OpenSSL that just happens to match an established public root. Do you maybe mean you generated a key and CSR (cert _request_) with OpenSSL and used the CSR to get a cert from a CA such as Comodo that is under (or bridges under) AddTrust External? Anyway, something is messed up in your files. Look in the Apache config to confirm what files are conifgured for SSLCertificateFile and (probably) SSLCertificateChainFile and look at what is actually in those files. `openssl x509 -noout -text <file` displays the details of a cert in a PEM file (but only one cert!)

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. I generated a key and then used Comodo to get the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Some file did change on disk and/or your Apache configuration has changed. Basically you are configuring Apache with a certificate and key but Apache tells you that they are not related together as they should.